Deriving relationship between total intensity and energy density for a black body
I have recently started learning Quantum Physics and I want to know more about black body radiations . The task is to prove that the total intensity (I) is related to energy density (u) by the relation :
I = cu/4
Please help me to derive this relation using geometrical interpretations .
